# How can I create command abbreviations (`ca`) with the lua api?

Tags: neovim, lua

In my `init.vim`, I have the following:

```
ca WQ wq
```

What would be the equivalent in my `init.lua`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*!!Note: this solution only works on Neovim >= v0.10; see @ruuter's answer if you are on an older version of neovim.*

Command abbreviation is treated as just another keymap mode by `nvim_set_keymap`. The equivalent of `ca WQ wq` in lua is:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("ca", "WQ", "wq")
```

I had a hard time discovering this, as the help text in `h: vim.keymap.set`/the `lua.txt` help file does not actually list out the modes! It does however tell you to see `h: nvim_set_keymap` which lives in the `api.txt` help file, and that's where abbreviations are mentioned!

Comment: Good answer (voted), but I can’t resist pointing out that this is yet-another-easier-in-plain-Vim(script) moment :)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I get `Shortname is too long` error. Instead this you can simply do `vim.cmd('ca WQ wq')`. Use `vim.cmd` to execute any vim command in lua script.

Comment: @ruuter what version of neovim are you using? It looks like support for abbreviated short names for this API was only added 4 months ago to nightly ([commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/42bbc4fabcf948ac6b8798b8992bcba1fc1d3e59#diff-9166179d1081e8d7f87e6df28d1cf66cf02a5ef0a94170f43133d26fc607a13c)).

Comment: Ah okay, tnx. I'm using latest stable, 0.9.2

Answer (score 2):

You can execute any vim script command with `vim.cmd`. So in your case:

```lua
vim.cmd('ca WQ wq')
```

Comment: While this was the solution I was using prior to making this question, my intention was to understand how to do this purely via Lua (i.e. no escape hatch to vimscript).

Answer (score 1):

```
vim.keymap.set('c',  'WQ', 'wq')
```

works for me on

```
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1703358377
```

where `'c'` is for command mode. See [Neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.keymap.set()) for details.

For instance, I've just used it to make help output into a vertical split:

```
vim.keymap.set('c', 'h', 'vert h')
```

## Update

It sort of works, but it makes the above substitution whenever you type `h`. I changed back to `vim.cmd` solution myself.